# apex error by creating interactive report page - error ORA-00600

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I want to create a new site which includes a page with Interactive Report,
but at the last step (Confirm the new Application) I get multiple error's
displayed as:

> Unable to create modules. ORA-20001: Create pages error. ORA-20001: Unable to create report page. ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [25027], [2], [0], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []
>   ORA-20001: Create pages error. ORA-20001: Unable to create report page. ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [25027], [2], [0], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []

Can anybody explain to me why or how did this happen?

If I try a nomal query (select * from table ), it works.

Comment: Looks like Apex is reporting an internal error `ORA-00600`. These are often due to an Oracle bug, or perhaps some corruption on your database. More help: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2011/11-sep/o51support-453463.html

Comment: .)after upgrade to oracle version from 11.2.02 to 11.2.03 .. same errors.
.)afterward we upgradet to the new APEX Version 4.2.3.00.08 - same error by upgrading APEX.
.)Deinstalled and Installed 
.)no error and it works  :-)

Comment: Probably a corruption then. Plus, you get the benefits of the upgrades :)